# The \"data\" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, fs, writefile

Hello I'm trying to write a file with nodejs and I give it a directory to save it in a mongodb database
But I get the error **The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined**
When I try and write a file

This is my **API**

```
router.post('/create2', (req, res) => {

    
    var tc = new Testcase({
        name: req.body.name,
        upload: fs.writeFile('./uploads/'+req.body.name+'.robot', req.body.step1 , function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;               console.log('Results Received');
          }),
        
        run : req.body.run,
        
        modify: req.body.modify,
        delete: req.body.delete,
        step1: req.body.step1,
        step2: req.body.step2,
        step3: req.body.step3,
        step4: req.body.step4,
        step5: req.body.step5,
        step6: req.body.step6,
        step7: req.body.step7,
    });
    tc.save((err, doc) => {
        if (!err) { res.send(doc); }
        else { console.log('Error in Employee Save :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });
});
```

this is my TestCase Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const testcaseSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type : String, required : true , unique : true},
    upload: String,
    run: String,
    modify: String,
    delete: String,
    step1: String,
    step2: String,
    step3: String,
    step4: String,
    step5: String,
    step6: String,
    step7: String,
    checked: { type: Boolean, default: false }

    
    });
module.exports = mongoose.model('testcase', testcaseSchema, 'testcases');
```

Comment: What is the value of `req.body.step1`?  Do a `console.log(req.body.step1)` and see what it is.

Comment: it gives me a '0' even when I fill it with a string using postman

Comment: Sorry it's 'undefined' not 0

Answer (score 0):

If `req.body.step1` is `undefined`, that explains the error as that's not something valid you can pass to `fs.writefile()`.  I can think of a couple reasons why `req.body.step1` would be `undefined`.

1. The POST is not including a `step1` field in the body of the data.
2. The content-type on the POST is incorrect and doesn't match the format of the body of the data in the post.
3. Your middleware for parsing the POST body into `req.body` is not configured properly or isn't running before this route or you haven't installed it at all.